# Grouping regex based on the previous grouping result

Tags: ruby, regex

I have some parameters that I have to sort into different lists. The prefix determines which list should it belong to.

I use prefixes like: `c`, `a`, `n`, `o` and an additional hyphen (`-`) to determine whether to put it in include l it or exclude list.

I use the regex grouped as:

```
/^(-?)([o|a|c|n])(\w+)/
```

But here the third group (`\w+`) is not generic, and it should actually be dependent on the second group's result. I.e, if the prefix is:

- 'c' or 'a' -> `/\w{3}/`
- 'o'  -> `/\w{2}/`
- else -> `/\w+/`

Can I do this with a single regex? Currently I am using an `if` condition to do so.

Example input:

Valid:

```
"-cABS", "-aXYZ", "-oWE", "-oqr", "-ncanbeanyting", "nstillanything", "a123", "-conT" (will go to c_exclude_list)
```

Invalid:

```
"cmorethan3chars", "c1", "-a1234", "prefizisnotvalid", "somethingelse", "oABC"
```

Output: for each arg push to the correct list, ignore the invalid.

```
c_include_list, c_exclude_list, a_include_list, a_exclude_list etc.
```

Comment: what is the input and expecter output

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense now. Your edit just invalidates the answers below. What the heck is c_exclude_list?

Comment: I tried to make it more readable and understandable, but there could still be things that aren't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
/(-?)\b([aocn])((?:(?<=[ac])\w{3}|(?<=o)\w{2}|(?<=n)\w+))\b/
```

The idea consists to use lookbehinds to check the previous character without including it in the capture group.

Comment: `(?<![aoc])` might as well check for `n`: `(?<=n)`

Answer (score 1):

Since version 2.0, Ruby has switched from [Oniguruma](http://www.geocities.jp/kosako3/oniguruma/) to [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo) (a fork of Oniguruma), which adds support for conditional regex, among other features.

So you can use the following regex to customize the pattern based on the prefix:

```
^-(?:([ca])|(o)|(n))?(?(1)\w{3}|(?(2)\w{2}|(?(3)\w+)))$
```

[**Demo at rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/vZq6XzqsjM)

Comment: No, ruby has no support for branch reset or conditional.

Comment: @nhahtdh, Ruby 2+ does

Comment: Seems that Ruby 2.0 uses a mod of [Oniguruma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oniguruma), named [Onigmo](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo), which adds the feature of conditional regex (among a few other features). The original Oniguruma has no support for conditional regex. The documentation of Regexp class is not updated, though.

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to include the some information about conditional regex in Ruby, since the information is missing from the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Is a single, mind-bending regex the best way to deal with this problem?

Here's a simpler approach that does not employ a regex at all.  I suspect that it would be at least as efficient as a single regex, considering that with the latter you must still assign matching strings to their respective arrays. I think it also reads better and would be easier to maintain.  The code below should be easy to modify if I have misunderstood some fine points of the question.

**Code**

```
def devide_em_up(str)
  h = { a_exclude: [], a_include: [], c_exclude: [], c_include: [],
        o_exclude: [], o_include: [], other_exclude: [], other_include: [] }  
  str.split.each do |s|
    exclude = (s[0] == ?-)
    s = s[1..-1] if exclude
    first = s[0]
    s = s[1..-1] if 'cao'.include?(first)
    len = s.size
    case first
    when 'a'
      (exclude ? h[:a_exclude] : h[:a_include]) << s if len == 3
    when 'c'
      (exclude ? h[:c_exclude] : h[:c_include]) << s if len == 3
    when 'o'
      (exclude ? h[:o_exclude] : h[:o_include]) << s if len == 2
    else
      (exclude ? h[:other_exclude] : h[:other_include]) << s
    end
  end
  h
end
```

**Example**

Let's try it:

```
str = "-cABS cABT -cDEF -aXYZ -oWE -oQR oQT -ncanbeany nstillany a123 " +
      "-conT cmorethan3chars c1 -a1234 prefizisnotvalid somethingelse oABC"

devide_em_up(str)
  #=> {:a_exclude=>["XYZ"], :a_include=>["123"],
  #    :c_exclude=>["ABS", "DEF"], :c_include=>["ABT"],
  #    :o_exclude=>["WE", "QR"], :o_include=>["QT"],
  #    :other_exclude=>["ncanbeany"], :other_include=>["nstillany"]}
```